# How to prevent other programs from connecting to the COM-port I'm using

Tags: python, pyserial, pymodbus, com-port

I am using python pymodbus library to read data from a COM port. When launched, the program reads data on the COM port, but if I connect to the same port by some other program, it intercepts the port and the work of my program is interrupted. How can I solve this problem and let the computer know that the port I'm using is already taken and no other programs can connect to it.
This is my connection:

```
client = ModbusClient(method='rtu', port=port, stopbits=2, bytesize=8, parity='N', baudrate=19200, timeout=1)
```

Comment: I'd suggest updating the question with a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Also, what have you tried?

Comment: Also, do you use Windows?

Comment: @ConstantinHong You will not be able to reproduce my mistake, because at least you need a com port to which you need to connect and receive some information. And you also need another program that can connect to it. Answering your second question, yes, I use Windows